# Compute $E\left(\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^dX_i^2\right)^{-1}\right)$ for i.i.d. standard normal random variables $(X_i)$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Does anyone know how to solve the following exercise?

Let $X_i$, $i=1,\ldots,d$ be i.i.d $\mathcal N(0,1)$ random variables. Show that for $d>2$,

$$E\left[ \frac1 {\sum_{i=1}^d X_i^2} \right] = \frac 1 {d-2}$$

I have tried to use that the sum of $X_i^2$ is a chi square...

Comment: Integrate $\int \frac{1}{x}f(x)dx$, where $f(x)$ is the pdf of chi-squared(d), by relating the integral to $C\cdot\int g(x)dx$, where $g(x)$ is the pdf of chi-squared(d-2), so that $\int g(x)dx=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $Y\sim\chi^2_d.$ Then
$$
f_Y(x)\,dx = \frac 1 {\Gamma(d/2)} \left( \frac x 2 \right)^{d/2 - 1} e^{-x/2} \, \frac {dx} 2 \quad \text{for } x \ge 0
$$
Consequently
\begin{align}
\operatorname{E} \left( \frac 1 Y \right) & = \int_0^\infty \frac 1 x f_Y(x)\,dx \\[10pt]
& = \int_0^\infty \frac 1 x \frac 1 {\Gamma(d/2)} \left( \frac x 2 \right)^{d/2 - 1} e^{-x/2} \, \frac {dx} 2 \\[10pt]
& = \frac 1 2\int_0^\infty \frac 1 u \frac 1 {\Gamma(d/2)} u^{d/2-1} e^{-u}\, du \\[10pt]
& = \frac 1 {2\Gamma(d/2)} \int_0^\infty u^{(d-2)/2 - 1} e^{-u}\,du \\[10pt]
& = \frac 1 {2\Gamma(d/2)} \cdot \Gamma\left(\frac{d-2} 2\right) \\[10pt]
& = \frac {2 \Gamma((d/2) - 1)} {2\Gamma(d/2)} \\[10pt]
& = \frac{\Gamma((d/2)-1)}{2\Big((d/2) - 1)\Big) \Gamma((d/2)-1)} = \frac 1 {d-2}. 
\end{align}